# How to know if a data table is filtered in Primefaces 5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, filter, datatable

Recently I have moved from JSF 2.0 to JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 3.5 to Primefaces 5

I have got a table which has filter on each column. filtering works well using primefaces 3.5

```
<p:dataTable  id="gwsReportAllPartListDataTable" 
                                          value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.gwsReportPartTwoList}" 
                                          var="report" 
                                          paginator="true" 
                                          rows="100"
                                          paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks} {CurrentPageReport}" 
                                          currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} #{dictionary['out_of']} {totalPages}" 
                                          emptyMessage="#{dictionary['nothing_is_here']}" 
                                          scrollable="true"
                                          scrollWidth="1221"
                                          scrollHeight="500">

                                <p:ajax event="filter"  listener="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.onFilterDataTable}" oncomplete="updateFilters()"/>

                                <p:column  styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 90px;position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['reporting_period']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.year}, #{report.gwsReportPartOne.quarter}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 90px;position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.contractNumber}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:80px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;" filterValue="">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['subsoil_user_contract_register_number']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.contractNumber}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 40px;position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.gwsType.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:30px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['gws_type']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.gwsType.code}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column id="tender_code" width="100" style="position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" styleClass="columnCustomClass" filterBy="#{report.skp.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:90px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['gws_code_by_skp']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.skp.code}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 150px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.description}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:140px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['item_name_and_short_description_of_purchased_gws']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.description}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 50px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.tenderType.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:40px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['purchase_way']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.tenderType.code}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementNumber}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['agreement_number']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementNumber}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.resultDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['tender_result_date']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.resultDate}" >
                                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStartDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['agreement_conclusion_date']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStartDate}" >
                                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementEndDate}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['agreement_deadline_date']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementEndDate}" >
                                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"/>
                                    </h:outputText>                                   
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 50px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStatus.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:40px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['agreement_status']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementStatus.code}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementSum}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['total_sum_of_agreement_without_vat']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsReportPartOne.agreementSum)}">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.plannedSum}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['planned_sum_in_gpz_without_vat']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsReportPartOne.plannedSum)}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.actuallyPaidSum}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['actually_paid_sum_for_report_period_of_agreement_without_vat']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsReportPartOne.actuallyPaidSum)}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column  styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 100px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px; background-color: #{two.gwsSumWithoutVatColor}" filterBy="#{report.gwsSumWithoutVat}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:90px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['tender_volume_without_vat_in_price']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.gwsSumWithoutVat)}">
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierBinOrIin}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['supplier_bin_iin']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierBinOrIin}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 150px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierName}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:140px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['supplier_gws_name']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierName}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 60px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierCountry.code}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:50px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['supplier_gws_country']}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.gwsReportPartOne.supplierCountry.code}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.kazcontent}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['local_content_piece']}, %" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{report.kazcontent}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                    <ui:remove><h:outputText value="#{report.kazcontentInService}" >
                                            <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                        </h:outputText></ui:remove>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnCustomClass" style="width: 80px; position:relative; padding-bottom: 30px;" filterBy="#{report.procurementSumOfLocalContentOfGws}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width:70px; position:absolute; bottom:4px;">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{dictionary['procurement_sum_of_local_content_of_tru']}, #{viewAllAnalyticsBean.getThTengeOrUsd()}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.convertValueToCurrentCurrency(report.procurementSumOfLocalContentOfGws)}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00#" locale="ru-RU"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:columnGroup type="footer">  
                                    <p:row>  
                                        <p:column footerText="#{dictionary['totals']}: " style="text-align:right"/>  
                                        <p:column footerText="" />  
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalAgreementSum}" />
                                        <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalPlannedSum}" />
                                        <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalActualPaid}" />
                                        <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalGwsSum}" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="" />
                                        <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.averageKazContent} %" />
                                        <p:column footerText="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.totalGwsLocalContent}" />
                                    </p:row>  
                                </p:columnGroup>  
                            </p:dataTable>
```

I have onFilterDataTable function which fires each time when user start to type to filter fields on each column.

```
public void onFilterDataTable(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Filter called");
        DataTable table = (DataTable) event.getSource();
        filteredGwsReportPartTwoList = table.getFilteredValue();
        isFiltered = filteredGwsReportPartTwoList.size() != gwsReportPartTwoList.size();
        countTotalsAndGenerateGwsReportPartOne(isFiltered);
    }
```

but in Primefaces shows me that getFilteredValue() returns null when Primefaces 3.5 returns ready filtered list.

What is the problem? And how to check if data table shows already filtered data on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in PF 5.0 you need to explicit define `filteredValue`:

```
<p:dataTable  id="gwsReportAllPartListDataTable" 
  value="#{viewAllAnalyticsBean.gwsReportPartTwoList}" 
  var="report" 
  paginator="true" 
  rows="100"
  paginatorTemplate="{PageLinks} {CurrentPageReport}" 
  currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} #{dictionary['out_of']} {totalPages}" 
  emptyMessage="#{dictionary['nothing_is_here']}" 
  scrollable="true"
  scrollWidth="1221"
  scrollHeight="500"

  filteredValue="#{someBeanOrScope.someList}">
```

Answer (score 2):

me the same thing has happened to move from version 3.5 to 4.0.
I solved the problem using remotecomand to call actionlistener method.

```
 <p:dataTable filterDelay="1000"  emptyMessage="No se encontraron elementos"  widgetVar="tb1"  
                             id="tablaFact" var="item" selection="#{listadoFacturasMB.selectedFactura}" selectionMode="single"  paginator="true" 
                             rows="20" rowKey="#{item.idFactura}" value="#{listadoFacturasMB.facturaUtilList}" filteredValue="#{listadoFacturasMB.filterFacturaUtilList}"> 

 <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="handleLoadStart();" update=":frm1:tablaFact :frm1:panelTotal"/>
   <p:column style="width:10%" headerText="Importe Total" id="cff3">                   
      <h:outputText value="#{item.importeTotal}"/>
   </p:column>                                 

   <p:column style="width:10%" headerText="Importe CUC" id="cjj3">                   
       <h:outputText value="#{item.importeCuc}"/>
   </p:column>                      
</p:dataTable> 
 <p:remoteCommand id="rcom" name="loadRemoteContent" process="@this" update="panelTotal, tablaFact"  
                     actionListener="#{listadoFacturasMB.filterListener2}"/>
```

Backingbean

```
  public void filterListener2() {
    try {
        if (filterFacturaUtilList != null) {
           //your code
            }               
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: filterListener() " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```